# Decreasing asymptotic time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

First of all, sorry about the rather extensive question.

I'm practicing my algorithm skills in codility. Currently, I'm trying to find a solution to [this problem](https://codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/max_counters/).

> You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two
>   possible operations on them:
>
> - increase(X) − counter X is increased by 1,
> - max counter − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.
>
> A non-empty zero-indexed array A of M integers is given. This
>   array represents consecutive operations:
>
> - if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
> - if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max counter.
>
> For example, given integer N = 5 and array A such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 3
> A[1] = 4
> A[2] = 4
> A[3] = 6
> A[4] = 1
> A[5] = 4
> A[6] = 4
> ```
>
> the values of the counters after each consecutive operation will be:
>
> ```
> (0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
> (0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
> (0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
> (2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
> (3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
> (3, 2, 2, 3, 2)
> (3, 2, 2, 4, 2)
> ```
>
> The goal is to calculate the value of every counter after all operations.
>
> Assume that the following declarations are given:
>
> ```
> struct Results {
>   int * C;
>   int L;
> };
> ```
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M);
> ```
>
> that, given an integer N and a non-empty zero-indexed array A
>   consisting of M integers, returns a sequence of integers representing
>   the values of the counters.
>
> The sequence should be returned as:
>
> - a structure Results (in C), or
> - a vector of integers (in C++), or
> - a record Results (in Pascal), or
> - an array of integers (in any other programming language).
>
> For example, given:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 3
> A[1] = 4
> A[2] = 4
> A[3] = 6
> A[4] = 1
> A[5] = 4
> A[6] = 4
> ```
>
> the function should return `[3, 2, 2, 4, 2]`, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> N and M are integers within the range [1..100,000]; each element of
>   array A is an integer within the range [1..N + 1].
>
> Complexity:
>
> - expected worst-case time complexity is O(N+M);
> - expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the    storage required for input arguments).
>
> Elements of input arrays can be modified.

---

Here is my attempt in [c](/questions/tagged/c):

```
struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M) {
    struct Results result;
    int i, j,
        maxCounter = 0;

    result.C = calloc(N, sizeof(int));

    result.L = N;

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        if (A[i] <= N) {
            result.C[A[i] - 1]++;
            if (result.C[A[i] - 1] > maxCounter) {
                maxCounter = result.C[A[i] - 1];
            }
        } else {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                result.C[j] = maxCounter;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The solution **does work**, but it fails on some performance tests. The issue is this algorithm is `O(N*M)` because of the nested loops. The problem states that the complexity in worst case should be `O(N+M)`.

I had some ideas of how unnest the loops, like storing how many times the `max counters` operation took place and somehow figuring out the proper way to sum it to the counters, but I couldn't materialize it.

Another possibility would be to find a way of setting all elements in `struct.C` at once, using something like `memset`, but I think this would be cheating.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If the code works, perhaps move to [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for an opinion?

Comment: `memset` has the same time complexity as setting the elements manually. The usual way to do this would involve a hash table, but C doesn't come with a hash table implementation built in; you may want to get one.

Comment: Agreed. Seems like a good [tag:performance] question over there. Voting to close as "Too Broad", since Stack Overflow usually does not deal with Code Review-Style questions. They have too many possible answers.

Comment: @WeatherVane: People keep saying that, but I don't think it makes sense. First, code that fails to meet its performance requirements is not working code. Second, in your actual job, would you submit unworkably slow code for code review?

Comment: @user2357112 actually Code Review considers code that's provably correct, but slow "working". Time is not always a criterion of "working". Some people don't even have the luxury of codereviews at their jobs (*~shudder*). Additionally CodeReview.SE has the tags [tag:time-limit-exceeded] and [tag:performance]. Such questions are on-topic there.

Comment: This is controversial, I know, but I think @user2357112 has a point.

Comment: So is this the "why is my code slow" equivalent of "why is my code not working"?

Comment: I refered to [codereview help](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and I'm not sure this question is suitable there.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I don't think so, because I know why it's slow (: I just don't know exactly how to make it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to thank you @Quinchilion and @JohnBollinger very much for your thorough analysis of the problem.

I've found an answer that passes both the correctness and performance tests. Here it is, fully commented:

```
struct Results solution(int N, int A[], int M) {
    struct Results result;

    int i,
        maxCounter = 0,
        lastMaxCounter = 0;

    result.C = calloc(N, sizeof(int));

    result.L = N;

    /* One way or another, We have to iterate over all the counter  
     * operations input array, which gives us an O(M) time...
     */
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        /* There is a little gotcha here. The counter operations
         * input array is 1-based, while our native C arrays are 0-based.
         * So, in order check if we have a `increment` or a `max counters`
         * operation, we have to consider the interval ]0, N].
         */
        if (A[i] > 0 && A[i] <= N) {
            /* This is an `increment` operation.
             *
             * First we need to check if there is no pending `max counter`
             * operation in this very counter.
             * This is done by checking if the value of current counter is
             * **less than** the value of `lastMaxCounter`.
             */
            if (result.C[A[i] - 1] < lastMaxCounter) {
                /* If it is, means that we have to discard the counter's
                 * current value and increment it from the value of
                 * `lastMaxCounter`.
                 */
                result.C[A[i] - 1] = lastMaxCounter + 1;
            } else {
                /* If it ain't, we just increment this counter's value.
                 */
                result.C[A[i] - 1]++;
            }

            /* We also want to keep track of the maximum counter value.
             */
            if (result.C[A[i] - 1] > maxCounter) {
                maxCounter = result.C[A[i] - 1];
            }
        } else {
            /* This is a `max counter` operation.
             * 
             * What we need to do is buffer the current `maxCounter`
             * in order to be able to update the counters later.
             */
            lastMaxCounter = maxCounter;
        }
    }

    /* At this point, if all counters have been incremented at least 
     * once after the last `max counter` operation, we are good to go.
     *
     * Since this is a rather pretentious assumption, we need to
     * double check it.
     *
     * We iterate over all counters, checking if any of them is lower
     * than the buffered `lastMaxCounter`. If it is, it means that no
     * `increment` was performed on this counter after the last
     * `max counter`, so this means that its value should be equal
     * to `lastMaxCounter`.
     *
     * This is an O(N) operation.
     *
     * So, the algorithm's time complexity is O(N) + O(M) = O(N+M)
     * and the space complexity is O(N).
     */
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (result.C[i] < lastMaxCounter) {
            result.C[i] = lastMaxCounter;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track by updating the maxCounter value as you go, instead of calculating it from scratch when you actually need it. A somewhat similar tactic might work for the problem of setting all counters to the current maximum. What if you keep track of the value you meant to reset the counters to, but only do so when it is really necessary?

Comment: I don't see how this can allow me to unest the loops. Could you be more specific? (:

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos It's less about figuring out how to "un-nest" the loop and more about optimizing the algorithm itself by not doing unneeded operations. As a clue, I think you're going to need one more variable outside of the loop and a couple of branches... I don't know what more I can say without giving out the answer. Try to give it a think, it'll hit you :)

Comment: The only unneeded operation I can see right the way is that I'm setting *all counters* to `maxCounter`. The alternative would be to verify if I need to do this, but I think a comparison operation takes more CPU time than an attribution one.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep track of the value you meant to reset the array elements"?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos What I meant is that instead of setting all counters to the same value, just remember that value. Next time you want to increment a counter, check against this value to figure out how to update the counter.

Comment: Got it! this seems promising

Comment: But I'd still have to iterate over the elements because I'd have to store the difference to the `maxCounter` for each one.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I don't think you have to. You can infer a value of any counter just by comparing it to the value maxCounter was set to at the time you got the "max counter" command.

Answer (score 3):

The loop nesting is a *symptom* of your problem, not the cause.  The essential problem here is that there can be *O*(`N`) non-trivial `MAX` operations, so you cannot afford for more than *O*(`1`) of them to have a cost exceeding *O*(`1`).  Whether you loop or not, either testing or updating the value of all `M` counters costs *O*(`M`), so if you implement the `MAX` operation in a way that requires doing one or both of those in the normal case, then the overall cost is *o*(`N`*`M`).

Supposing that you track the global maximum as you update counters, as indeed you do, you can implement `MAX` in a manner that does not process all the counters immediately.  Instead, you can keep a record of the time when a `MAX` operation was most recently applied, the global maximum at that time, and a per-counter record of when a `MAX` operation was last applied *to that counter*.

In that event, whenever you perform an update on a particular counter, you can check whether there was a previous `MAX` operation that needs to be applied to it first, and what value to apply.  All of that is *O*(`1`), so the cost of each update remains *O*(`1`).  The `MAX` operation itself requires only updating two scalars, so that also is *O*(`1`).  Processing all the instructions therefore costs *O*(`M`).  At the end, you must make one pass through the counters to apply any remaining un-applied `MAX` operations; this costs *O*(`1`) for each of `N` counters.  Overall cost: *O*(`N`+`M`).

Note that this exhibits a classic space vs. speed tradeoff.  The simple-minded approach to the problem has *O*(`1`) memory overhead, but worse asymptotic complexity in terms of number of operations.  The alternative solution outlined above has better asymptotic complexity in number of operations, but requires *O*(`N`) memory overhead.

**Update:**

But as @Quinchilion rightly observes, you can do even better.  Consider that the correct current value of each counter is the value set by the last `MAX` operation plus the number of increments performed on that counter since the last `MAX`.  No counter's value ever decreases.  Therefore, we don't need to explicitly track the timing of `MAX` operations -- the most recent value recorded for each counter inherently indicates whether the last `MAX` still needs to be applied.  If it is less than the maximum counter value recorded at the time of the latest `MAX`, then that `MAX` has to be applied before the increment; otherwise, not.  This can be combined with the approach described above to eliminate the need for an auxiliary array.

Comment: I believe you don't need any extra per-counter record at all. Since the only other operation done on the counters is a simple increment, you can tell whether a previous MAX operation was done on it already by comparing it to the global maximum at that time. If it's less, you store last_global_max + 1, otherwise you increment as usual.

Comment: @Quinchilion, you are right.  I have added a description of that alternative to my answer.